# Zeppelin: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD does not exist

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, pyspark, py4j, apache-zeppelin

#### IPython notebook

Started as per docs (`PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" ./bin/pyspark`), then filled in with:

```
from os import path
from tempfile import gettempdir

#from pyspark import SparkFiles


filename = path.join(gettempdir(), 'somefile.txt')

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(['foo\n'*500])

#sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSort")
sc.addFile(filename)

print 'sc.textFile(filename).count() =', sc.textFile(filename).count()

sc.stop()
```

Output: `sc.textFile(filename).count() = 500`

#### Apache Zeppelin notebook

```
%pyspark
# Then same as "IPython notebook"
```

Output:

`(<class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JError'>, Py4JError(u'An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD. Trace:\npy4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD([class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD, class [B, class java.util.HashMap, class java.util.ArrayList, class java.lang.Boolean, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.util.ArrayList, class org.apache.spark.Accumulator]) does not exist\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:184)\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:202)\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:213)\n\tat py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)\n\tat py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n\n',), <traceback object at 0x7f3f79e24440>)`

Comment: You can simplify your pyspark setup with https://github.com/minrk/findspark in IPython.

Comment: Thanks, that library was useful on Windows.